# How to enable multicast function in a podman container?

Tags: podman

run a container in rootless podman.

```
$ podman run -i -t --rm alpine
```

in container

```
# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: tap0: <BROADCAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65520 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 4a:b3:e1:90:e3:5e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.100/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global tap0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::48b3:e1ff:fe90:e35e/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Can not enable multicast function

```
# ifconfig tap0 multicast
ifconfig: ioctl 0x8914 failed: Operation not permitted
```